# Android + ROS + QR

Tags: java, android

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I just started with ROS and I want to make an android app that reads a QR code to decide which information it should send. After deciding which information it should send, a node should receive it and do something. The information would be a position in the world.

May I ask how I should start?
I don't know the approach I should take:
-Should I make a common android app and find a way to send the information? How can I send it to a node without the app being a node?
-Should I run a node in the cel phone and send the information via a topic?

I am quite lost because I don't know java and I am new to ROS. Not sure which approach would be easier or better.

Thanks in advance for your help.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/149866/android-+-ros-+-qr/) by [Elvish Champion](https://answers.ros.org/users/13736/elvish-champion/) on ROS Answers with karma: 165 on 2014-04-07

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There is already some code in the rosjava repositories which do this. The [zebra crossing - zxing](https://github.com/rosjava/android_extras/tree/hydro) is a library that does the qr codes. A simple RosActivity from android_core should let you build the basis of an app which can publish whatever information you want from the qr code to a ros node on another system. You can grep through the [android_apps](https://github.com/rosjava/android_apps/tree/hydro) and [android_remocons](https://github.com/rosjava/android_remocons/tree/hydro) code to find usage of zxing.

---

Originally posted by [Daniel Stonier](https://answers.ros.org/users/51/daniel-stonier/) with karma: 3170 on 2014-04-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Elvish Champion](https://answers.ros.org/users/13736/elvish-champion/) on 2014-04-19**:
Thanks you have been a great help. I am running the PubSub app from android_core. The message "Hello World! #" appears in my cell phone since it establishes communication with my pc. However, I am unable to see that message with rostopic echo /chatter  . May I ask what am I doing wrong? Thanks.

**Comment by [Elvish Champion](https://answers.ros.org/users/13736/elvish-champion/) on 2014-04-19**:
Using rqt_graph I can see rostpic is suscribed to /chatter in the Nodes/Topic(All) tab. However only rostopic appears in Nodes/Topics(Active). I suppose that the publisher isn't publishing new content to /chatter, but that seems strange since "Hello World! #" keeps increasing. Thanks =)